# How to check list against tokenized column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nltk

The general idea is to write a script comparing words from a seedlist with words in an utterance. Therefore I tried to

- [x] parse an xml-file
- [x] make a pandas DataFrame
- [ ] compare it with a set of words stored in a variable called "hedge"
- [ ] highlight the words matching the words stored in the variable
- [ ] give back the matching "utterance" with "name" and "id"
- [x] write everything in file (xml or csv)

The xml-corpus is structured as follows:

```
<section name="thisisaxml-file">
    <topic>
        <utterance name="John Doe" id="264">
            foo bar?
        </utterance>
        <utterance name="Henry Parker" id="265">
            foo foo bar. New York, wind. 
        </utterance>
    </topic>
</section>
```

Because of my marvelous, self-taught python skills that's what I came up with so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

#xml file data input
xml_data = 'sample.xml'

#create an ElementTree object 
etree = ET.parse(xml_data)
doc_df = pd.DataFrame(list(iter_docs(etree.getroot())))

hedge = ['foo', 'wind', 'base']
df = pd.DataFrame({'utterance': doc_df['utterance']})
df['id'] = pd.DataFrame({'id': doc_df['id']})
df['name'] = pd.DataFrame({'name': doc_df['name']})
df['tokenized_sents'] = df.apply(lambda row: word_tokenize(row['utterance']), axis=1)
df['sents_length'] = df.apply(lambda row: len(row['tokenized_sents']), axis=1)

final = df[df.tokenized_sents.apply(lambda x: hedge in x)]
final.to_csv('out.csv', sep='\t', encoding='utf-8') #prints to file
```

There are a few problems I stumbled upon:

1. `df['tokenized_sents'].lower()` isn't working because (I think) of list format in `pd.DataFrame(list(iter_docs(etree.getroot())))`
2. `df[df.tokenized_sents.apply(lambda x: hedge in x)]` works, but doesn't give back anything, but if you're using a string it works.
3. tried to highlight the found words, failed

So in general I would like to check a list of words against a specific column in pandas. While I have seen similar topics on this site, none of the mentioned solutions worked for me so far.

Do you have any ideas for me?

Answer (score 0):

The variable df is already a dataframe with a dictionary in it. Creating dataframes in dataframes corrupts your data, or at least I've seen it corrupt some of mine. If that's not always the case I'd love a reference on how to do that. 
Anyways, dunno if this will fix your issues, but it will for sure clean up your code.

```
hedge = ['foo', 'wind', 'base']
df = pd.DataFrame({
                 'utterance': doc_df['utterance'],
                  'id':doc_df['id'],
                  'name':doc_df['name']})
df['tokenized_sents'] = df.apply(lambda row:word_tokenize(row['utterance']),axis=1)
df['sents_length'] = df.apply(lambda row: len(row['tokenized_sents']), axis=1)
```